# Can visiting a website virus your computer if you have JavaScript disabled?

Tags: javascript, virus

Let's say I visit a website that could potentially infect my computer by just from visiting it. If I disable JavaScript, is it still possible to infect my computer?

I have already searched the site for this question, but I only find questions like this that don't mention disabling JavaScript

Comment: Don't forget about Web Assembly: https://github.com/stevespringett/disable-webassembly  Neither Javascript or Web Assembly will install malware if the browser "sandbox" holds up, but they could perform other attacks that would steal credentials and or trick you into giving credentials.  Browser extensions/plugins/addons are much more dangerous than client-side scripting/assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Javascript is widely used for malware infection, and it's by far the most used way, but it's not the only vector for infection. If you run any vulnerable extension, or the browser uses any outdated library, then a specially crafted element can lead to code execution even without Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling JavaScript can be helpful, but it is not sufficient, here is some additional information from MalwareByte: [How do I get malware?](https://www.malwarebytes.com/malware/)

> Malware can penetrate your computer when (deep breath now) you surf through hacked websites, view a legitimate site serving malicious ads, download infected files, install programs or apps from unfamiliar provide, open a malicious email attachment (malspam), or pretty much everything else you download from the web on to a device that lacks a quality anti-malware security application.

Answer (score 1):

Of course!
There are several vectors of attack available. For example, think about browser exploits where an adversary could obtain code execution taking advantage of a browser's vulnerability. Another really cool example would be the extensions that browsers allow you to install to extend functionalities.